# How to use <- with strip_tags? I've tried converting the symbols before and after with no luck

Tags: php, str-replace, strip-tags

Okay... I know <- cant be excluded from strip_tags using allowable tags per say but im trying to use a work around. The work around works fine on character sets that wouldn't be valid HTML to begin with, such as << or <~ however when i use the code below to convert the <- or -> to digits before strip_tags is processed and then back from digits to the <- and -> after. But whenever those symbols show up all HTML from there on is removed, that or not processed. I understand i cant have it left alone through allowable tags which is why i convert it before the strip_Tags and back after... but its almost as if strip_Tags still removes it even though its converted back after the line where strip_tags is, since its removing <- and taking everything to the right of it.... Any ideas or other ways to try? I've also tried defining <- as `&lt;—` and tried replacing it with other symbols as well, such as #- but no matter what i have the same outcome.

I should also mention the <- and -> arent used together, they are used to point to things in text. Like internt <- is misspelled there.

```
`<?php 
$data = file_get_contents("test.html");
$data = str_replace("<-", "999", $data);
$data = str_replace("->", "998", $data);
$data = strip_tags($data, '');
$data = str_replace("999", "<-", $data);
$data = str_replace("998", "->", $data);
echo $data;
?>`
```

I was gathering sample data and realize if i remove a good chunk of the sample HTML everything works fine, turns out if i strip actual HTML comments such as `<!-- Header //-->` on my own the conversion goes fine, so im going to look for a regex match to remove the HTML comments before the conversion and the striptags.

**Update**

I used the following code below to remove the HTML comments first, which results in success. Thanks for your help.

```
`$data = preg_replace('/<!--(.*)-->/', '', $data);`
```

Comment: You've got other problems if you're converting to something else, then back, and it is still stripped.  Its pretty much not possible.  post some code.

Comment: Why don't you edit your question and put it in there so its readable.  And it'd be useful to at least include a small sample of your input data including the tags in question.

Comment: Is it possible to change the source to use proper entities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

```
$string = "<div>words words wrods <- words words</div>";
$string = str_replace('<-', '&lt;-', $string);
echo strip_tags($string);
```

**Output (Source):**

```
words words wrods &lt;- words words
```

**Output (HTML):**

```
words words wrods <- words words
```

Comment: Sorry i should of explained, the <- aren't actually used as a tag they are used in the middle of text like a pointer. Like internt <- that word is misspelled. Which is why im assuming everything from the <- on is being stripped since its considered one big tag, but what doesnt make sense is at the time the strip_Tags is processed <- is still converted to 999...

Comment: @Ryan: I've updated my answer, see if that works for you. If not, could you please post more specific code that shows your issue?